# Live agent not connecting VF page.?

Tags: apex, visualforce, liveagent

I am unable to connect.When i click on chat..It just stays on the page ..
*"Please hold while we connect you to an agent."* and no window is popped up in Console.

Please help its really very urgent for me.Below is my complete code.If i remove my lead code and just call directly the chat code..It works fine.Please help me on this.Please suggest what could be wrong

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="PreChatController">

<apex:variable var="deploymentId" value="572260000004C9w" />
<apex:variable var="orgId" value="**************" />
<apex:variable var="buttonId" value="573260000004CAB" />

<!-- This script takes the endpoint URL parameter passed from the deployment page and makes
it the action for the form -->
<!--<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la1-c2cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/34.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    liveagent.init('https://d.la1-c2cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '{!deploymentId}', '{!orgId}');   
</script>-->

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la1-c2cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/34.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
liveagent.init('https://d.la1-c2cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572260000004C9w', '**********');
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() 
    {
        function handlePageLoad()
        {
            var endpointMatcher = new RegExp("[\\?\\&]endpoint=([^&#]*)");
            document.getElementById('prechatForm').setAttribute('action',
            decodeURIComponent(endpointMatcher.exec(document.location.search)[1]));
        } 
        if (window.addEventListener) 
        {
            window.addEventListener('load', handlePageLoad, false);
        } 
        else 
        { 
            window.attachEvent('onload', handlePageLoad, false);
        }
    })();

    if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }

    window._laq.push(function()
    {
        liveagent.showWhenOnline('{!buttonId}', document.getElementById('prechat_submit'));
        liveagent.showWhenOffline('{!buttonId}', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_{!buttonId}'));
    });

    function getLeadOrContact()
    {
        console.log('Getting lead or contact');
        var emailAddr = document.getElementById('email').value.trim();
        var fname = document.getElementById('name').value.trim();
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value.trim();

       /* try
        {*/
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.PreChatController.findLeadOrContactByEmail}', 
                fname,
                emailAddr,
                phone, 
                function(result, event)
                {
                    if (event.status) 
                    {
                        console.log(result);
                        if(result.Id.substring(0,3) === '003')
                        {
                            document.getElementById('contactid').value = result.Id;
                        }
                        else if(result.Id.substring(0,3) === '00Q')
                        {
                            document.getElementById('leadid').value = result.Id;
                        }
                        document.forms["prechatForm"].submit();

                        return true;
                    } 
                }, 
                {escape: false}
            );
       /* }
        catch(ex)
        {
            alert(ex.message);
            console.log(ex);
            return false;
        }*/
        return false;
    }   

</script>
<style>
body
{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
#chatFormDiv
{
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#chatHeader
{
    color:#6d6d6d;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
label
{
    width:150px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
input[type=text], textarea
{
    width:200px;
    background: #f3f3f3; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f3f3f3 0%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f3f3f3), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f3f3f3 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f3f3f3 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f3f3f3 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f3f3f3 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f3f3f3', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */    
    border-color: #dedede;
    border-top-color: #d3d3d3;
}
textarea
{
    height:140px;
}
.chatStatusDiv
{
    display:none;
}
</style>

<div  style="top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; position: absolute;" id="window_outer">
    <img src="https://c.cs81.visual.force.com/resource/1443071670000/ChatImage" /> <span id="chatHeader"></span><br/>
    <hr />

    <form method='post' id='prechatForm' onsubmit="return false;" action="https://15af.la7cs.salesforceliveagent.com/content/s/chat?language=en_US#deployment_id={!deploymentId}&org_id={!orgId}&button_id={!buttonId}">

    <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat.name' id='name' placeholder="Your Name" required="required"/><br />

    <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:Email' id='email' placeholder="Email Address" required="required" /><br />

    <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:Phone' id='phone' placeholder="Phone" required="required" /><br />

    <textarea name='liveagent.prechat:Body' id='body' placeholder="Message" required="required" ></textarea><br />

    <input name="liveagent.prechat.buttons" value="{!buttonId}" type="hidden" /><br />

    <!-- Creates an auto-query for a matching Contact record’s Email field based on the
    value of the liveagent.prechat:Email field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.query:Email" value="Contact,Contact.Email" />

    <!--- populate fields ---->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.query:Email" value="Lead,Lead.Email" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.save:Email"  value="Provided_Email__c" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.save:name"   value="Provided_Name__c" />
    <input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:ContactId'   value='' id='contactid'/>  
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.save:ContactId" value="Contact" />

    <input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:LeadId' id='leadid' />  
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.save:LeadId" value="Lead" />

    <!--- Button that shows up if someone is online --->    
    <img   src="https://c.cs81.visual.force.com/resource/1443071650000/ChatButton" 
           alt="Submit Form" 
           onclick="getLeadOrContact()"
           id='prechat_submit'
           style="display: none; border: 0px none; cursor: pointer; float: left;"/>

    <!--- Button that shows up if nobody is online --->
    <img id="liveagent_button_offline_{!buttonId}" 
         style="display: none; border: 0px none; cursor: pointer; float: left;" 
         src="https://c.cs81.visual.force.com/resource/1443071650000/ChatButton" 
         onclick="alert('nobody online, put your redirect here');"/>

    </form>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**

```
global class PreChatController
{

    @remoteAction
    global static sobject findLeadOrContactByEmail(string name, string email, string phone)
    {
        sObject returnObject; //the id that will store the contact or lead this chat is related to
        //first we should see if there is a contact with this email
        list<contact> contacts = [select accountid, name, id, email from contact where email = :email limit 1];
        if(!contacts.isEmpty())
        {
            return contacts[0];
        }

        //if there is no contact, then lets look for a lead instead. Yeah we could combind both queries into a single SOSL search, but the code for that doesn't
        //end up being much cleaner when you account for having to figure out what record to return when you have a list of lists.
        else
        {
            list<lead> leads = [select name, id, email from lead where email = :email limit 1];
            if(!leads.isEmpty())
            {
                return leads[0];
            }
            else
            {            
                lead thisLead = new lead();
                string[] nameParts = name.split(' ');

                thisLead.firstname = nameParts.size() > 1 ? nameParts[0] : ''; //if name parts contains more than one element that means we likely got a full name and the first part is the firstname. Otherwise nothing
                thisLead.lastname =  nameParts.size() > 1 ? nameParts[1] : nameParts[0]; //if name parts is greater than 1 then use the 2nd element as the lastname. Otherwise use the first element
                thisLead.phone = phone;
                thisLead.email = email;
                thisLead.company = name;
                thisLead.leadSource = 'Web Site';

                insert thisLead;
                return thisLead;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the logs to see if the lead code is causing an exception, or try wrapping the code in a try catch block in order to ensure everything works?

Comment: Log is perfectly fine.. No issues amywhere??any other suggestion?